# Filter-branch filters out directory within subdirectory

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

I'm using following command to filter some subdirectory with its history:

```
git filter-branch -f --prune-empty --subdirectory-filter path-to/subdir -- --all
```

where subdir has following hierarchy:

```
subdir/
    a/
    b/
    c/
```

The problem is, when the processing is finished while `a` and `b` is preserved, `c` is removed from history (and the whole directory is marked as new files). Everybody seems to be happy with the command, what's the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently `c` has an ignored directory, when I execute `git status` git says `there are untracked files in subdir/c`. I copied my original `.gitignore` file and everything is fine.